# how return map in hibernate sql query

Tags: hibernate

```
class Tets{
long id;
Map<String,String> map;
}



 <sql-query name="xxx">
        <return-scalar column="id" type="long"/>
--- similar part
        <return class="java.util.HashMap" >
            <return-property name="code" column="code"/>
            <return-property name="value" column="value"/>
        </return>
 <![CDATA[

select id  ,code , value
from Table

]]>
    </sql-query>
```

**I want return map and set into map object and jsut using sql query??**
hibernate mapping has'n enough mapping in sql querys;

Answer (score 0):

I write new Transformer than convert map to object with jakcess rowMapper library
and in sql query of hibernate create similar json in query with special alies (Map)
and string type.